# Let$ f(x)=12x+12-17e^x$.

Tags: calculus

Then the equation of the tangent line to the graph of $f(x)$ at the point $( 0 , -5 )$ is given by $$y=m x + b$$

for 
m= **__
b= __**

I've gotten the derivative as $12+17e^x$. I'm not sure what to do with it from there.

Comment: Hint: point-slope form.

Comment: I think you want a minus sign instead of a plus sign, but now you want to substitute $x=0$ to get the slope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put $x=0$ to $12-17e^x$, you get $12-17 \cdot e^0=12-17=-5$. It's your $m$. Next put $x=0$, $y=-5$ and $m=-5$ to equation $y=mx+b$, you get $b$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that 
$$f'(x)=12\color{red}{-}17e^x.$$
Then, the slope of the line is $f'(0)$ and it passes through $(0,-5)$, namely, 
$$y-(-5)=f'(0)(x-0)\Rightarrow y=-5x-5.$$